# how to remove other noise from image using opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

Here I am using below script to remove black spot near the image and remove line-through above number but it removes noise but not properly.

```py
def get_string(img_path):
    # Read image with opencv
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)

    # Convert to gray
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=12)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=12)

    # Write image after removed noise
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise.png", img)

    #  Apply threshold to get image with only black and white
    img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 31, 2)

    # Write the image after apply opencv to do some ...
    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "thres.png", img)

    # Recognize text with tesseract for python
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "vertical_final.jpg"))

    # Remove template file
    #os.remove(temp)

    return result
```

but it's not working properly.

Input image:

[image: img]

Output Image:-

[image: img]

I need someone to help me out from these problems it's highly appreciated.
Source Code:-

```py
def get_string(img_path):
    # Read image with opencv
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)

    # Convert to gray
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
    kernel = np.ones((1,20), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    #img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    #img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise.png", img)

    img3 = cv2.subtract(cv2.imread(src_path + "removed_noise.png"),cv2.imread(src_path + "tax_amount.png"))

    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise_makes_00.png", img3)

    lower_black = np.array([0,0,0], dtype = "uint16")
    upper_black = np.array([70,70,70], dtype = "uint16")
    black_mask = cv2.inRange(img3, lower_black, upper_black)
    black_mask[np.where((black_mask == [0] ).all(axis = 1))] = [255]

    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(black_mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise_makes_00_1.png", opening)

    # Recognize text with tesseract for python
    result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "removed_noise_makes_00_1.png"))

    # Remove template file
    #os.remove(temp)

    return result
```

Comment: Do you know what your code does? Why do you expect it to remove the line but not the text?

Comment: because after that i want to use that image in python tesseract if i am using same image then it's not generate proper output.

Comment: I didn't ask why you want to remove the line, but why did you think your code would remove the line? Are you familiar at all with mathematical morphology? I ask because I'd like to know if you are looking to understand how to solve this, or just want a ready-made solution.

Comment: No i want to understand because i am not aware with image processing if you can help me then thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Where you do

```
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=12)
```

You apply 12 times a dilation with a 1x1 structuring element (SE). Unless OpenCV does something special with such a SE, this code should not change your image at all.

You should create a larger SE:

```
kernel = np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
```

This will first dilate and then erode the result. What this accomplishes is that small (thin) black regions disappear. These are the regions where the SE didn't fit. This is the same as

```
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

To remove the long line, you want to apply a closing with an elongated SE:

```
kernel = np.ones((1, 30), np.uint8)
line = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

This leaves only the horizontal line. The difference of `img` and `line` is the text without the line.

If you think of `img` as the sum of `line` and `text`, then `img - line` will be `text`. However, there is a small problem still: `img` has white background (255), and black foreground. So really, it is `img = 255 - text - line`, and the `line` image you found above is really `255 - line`, because it also has white background. So directly taking the difference will not produce the desired effect.

The solution is to invert your images first:

```
img = 255 - img;
line = 255 - line;
text = img - line;
```

Comment: i have apply kernel = np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1) but it's create blank image here my code https://repl.it/repls/MundaneVioletHadrosaurus

Comment: The 7 is too large then. It means that the SE didn't fit anywhere, and so everything is removed. Make it smaller so that the noise is removed but the letters are not. You need to tweak these parameters until it works!

Comment: kernel = np.ones((2, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=3)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=3) applied these line remove but digit also remove https://ibb.co/bzE0RS

Comment: You set `iterations` to 3. Keep it at 1 and only adjust the `kernel`. It'll be easier to see what happens. Display the kernel, compare the size to the structures you're trying to remove. It should be larger than what you want to remove, but smaller than what you want to keep.

Comment: To remove the line you want a kernel that is elongated in the same direction as the line -- that'll remove the letters but keep the line! The the difference between that image and the original is the letters without the line.

Comment: i tried kernel = np.ones((4, 1), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1) these option line remove but text also little remove look like these image https://ibb.co/bzE0RS

Comment: You're creating a vertical kernel, make a horizontal one: `np.ones((1,20),...)`.

Comment: but that will remove text and display only line .

Comment: Bingo! And what can you do with that? We know that "img = text + line". You know "img", you now have found "line", how do you get "text"?

Comment: yes you are right text = img - line but how can i do it that didn't on your above explnation i know how to get line now using that line remove from img that i didn't know

Comment: @DhavalBhavsar: I've updated the answer to explain the issues with the white background. Try to think of the images not as black and white, but as a set of numbers. You are working with those numbers. Morphology is all about what is larger and what is smaller. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for helping to these level but if i am subtract line from image that image text cut i want that clear so final solution done

Comment: Please i updated my question and add final image and i am on final stage i want to complete that cut text means 24.90 with complete text you can see in output image some pixel white in 2 4 9 and 0 i want to make black so final image can see it. is it possible?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but it's way too hard for a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If i need to paid then it's fine for me.